# Return last 3 digits of a string separately

Tags: php

So let's say I have the following string:

```
$exampleString = "8b1a9953c4611296a827abf8c47804d7";
```

How could I return the last 3 digits of this string separately?

By that I mean I'd like to have 3 variables, let's say `$thirdLastCharacter`, `$secondLastCharacter` and `$lastCharacter`, and have them equal to "4", "d" and "7" in this case.

The last one would be easy, as I could simply do:

```
$lastCharacter = substr($exampleString,-1);
```

and that would give me "7", but I'm not sure how I'd do it for the others.

How could I do this?

Comment: `$last haracter = substr($exampleString, -3);` check function here http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: I don't think you properly understood my question.

Comment: so u need in for each variable diferent char ? from last 3

Comment: Yes, that's what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
$lastCharacter = substr($exampleString,-1);

$secondLastCharacter = $exampleString[strlen($exampleString)-2];

$thirdLastCharacter = $exampleString[strlen($exampleString)-3];
```

Answer (score 1):

There u go

```
$exampleString = "8b1a9953c4611296a827abf8c47804d7";

// returns d
$secondLastCharacter = substr($exampleString, -2, 1);

// returns 4
$thirdLastCharacter = substr($exampleString, -3, 1);

// returns 7 
$lastCharacter = substr($exampleString, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$exampleString = "8b1a9953c4611296a827abf8c47804d7";
$LastCharacters = substr($exampleString,-3);
$ret=str_split($LastCharacters);
echo $ret[0];
echo $ret[1];
echo $ret[2];
```